# Laravel how can I Update multiple record of same columns

Tags: php, laravel

[image]I try to make update records. Here is my code:

```
|id | first_section_thumbnail |
|-----------------------------|
| 1 | 1                       |
| 2 | NULL                    |
| 3 | 1                       |
| 4 | 1                       |
| 5 | NULL                    |
| 6 | NULL                    |
```

I want to update `first_section_thumbnail` values. How can I do this in query builder?

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="first_section_thumbnail" name="first_section_thumbnail[]" value="1" <?php if ($row->first_section_thumbnail == 1) { echo "checked"; } ?>>
  Added to Slider <i class="input-helper"></i>
</label>
```

```
$id = $request->id;
$first_section_thumbnail=$request->first_section_thumbnail;
$array = [
  'id'=>$id,
  'first_section_thumbnail'=>$first_section_thumbnail
];

DB::table('posts')
->whereIn('id', $array['id'])
->update(array('first_section_thumbnail' => false));
```

Comment: Your code should work fine, but `$first_section_thumbnail` is not being used at all, and `whereIn('id', $array['id'])` seems redundant if you're only targeting a single ID. Please explain your issue with more detail; what is going wrong? What is your expected outcome? Are there any errors?

Comment: ` <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input"   id="first_section_thumbnail" name="first_section_thumbnail[]"
   value="1" <?php if ($row->first_section_thumbnail == 1) {
echo "checked";
} ?>>
                                                    Added to Slider <i class="input-helper"></i></label>`  This is my blade file.I want to when i click checkbox first_section_thumbnail updated to 1 and when i unclick this first_section_thumbnail will be 1  and when i unclick this first_section_thumbnail will be null

Comment: @Creator__Lech null or false? and what is exacly the problem?

Comment: Exactly problem is,at rn when i click all posts and then click save,all posts turn the null.But i want to only not clicked posts turns null.Clicked posts be 1

Comment: this sounds to be a very bad database design to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

your whereIn is wrong, because you are doing a whereIn on a int and not an array,

you should do :

```
DB::table('posts')
->where('id', $id)
->update(array('first_section_thumbnail' => false));
```

Comment: Nope.My main problem is when i click all posts and then click save,all posts turn the false.But i want to only not clicked posts turns false.Clicked posts be 1